# How to interpret auction/issuance results?

Tags: bonds, auction

If a new bond (issuance size of 300M) was 3X covered and had 40 buyers, what does it mean?

Comment: It means that there were bids to buy 900M ( 3 * 300M) worth of bonds from 40 different buyers. Is that what you want to know, or do you want to know the _significance_ of those results?

Comment: @DStanley I would guess there could have been bids to buy 900M worth of bonds from _more_ than 40 (potential) buyers, but only 40 of them were successful.

Comment: @TripeHound That is probably correct (otherwise they would have been called "bidders")

Comment: So the deal was well received then given that the issuer just wanted to borrow 300M. Now my question would be. is it possible for the to increase the amount the issuer want to borrow?